# Online and/or Instructor led training - Grails

Tags: java, grails, groovy

Am looking for training (preferably online but in-person would work as well) for Groovy And Grails for not so expensive price. Something which starts from scratch and gives you enough information over a period of time.

Comment: It's called Grails, not "Groovy on Grails"

Comment: SpringSource - the "owners of Groovy & Grails" - offer on-site and off-site training http://www.springsource.com/training/course?courseID=18353

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that the guys from [ThirstyHead](http://thirstyhead.com/) are giving trainings and conduct consulting for Groovy/Grails. Maybe you can ping them. I am not sure about their prices though.